# How to Create TensorLiteModel in swift

Tags: ios, swift, tensorflow, face-recognition

I want to create the TFLite model, I want Face recognition in real-time. I have gone through multiple tutorials but I am unable to understand how I can create the Model in Swift code. basically, I want to convert the face image into Vector form which I can later use for face recognition.
Please help me to create tensorFlowModel in Swift.
you can share the tutorial link also .